# MS-Excel: Calculate Address Range for SUM function

Tags: excel-formula

Define Excel's cell P1 =494 an integer:  the integer represents index of the final row of a table.

Goal: calculate the sum from the K column: =SUM(columnK,row2 : ColumnK rowP1).   The idea is that if cell P1 s update from 494 to 508, the sum of the column K will change from 494th to 508th row.

Answer (score 1):

INDIRECT() function:

[image]

Reference: https://www.exceltip.com/summing/summing-values-in-a-range-specified-by-indirect-cell-references.html